# how to check string with column which have specific word in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `invalidtext`. In this table I have records like

```
+----+---------+
| id |  text   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Yahoo   |
|  2 | Gmail   |
|  3 | Windows |
+----+---------+
```

Now I have a string like

> hello yahoo how are you?

I want to check if "hello yahoo how are you?" contains any word which is in `invalidtext` table.

We can see `yahoo` word is in this table, so record should have to be find.

Which query will work to search ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select text
from invalidtext
where '$input' like concat('%', text, '%')
```

Comment: @NikulPanchal: Beware that any occurrences of `_`, `%` or ``\`` within `invalidtext.text` will have a special meaning (as described under [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) in the manual): this may in fact be an advantage to you, since you can then use patterns in the table rather than exact text, though if it's undesirable you must be sure to escape their use (if any).  As an aside, if you want to have more advanced pattern matching, you could use MySQL's [`RLIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) operator instead.